# How do I get the PropertyDescriptor for the elements of an array?

Tags: java, introspection

I have the PropertyDescriptor of an array field that looks like below.

`Foo[] fooArray;`

How can I get the PropertyDescriptor for `Foo`, so that I am able to get the getter and setter methods of the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `Class` object represents an array type, you can ask for the element type:

```
Class<?> clazz = Foo[].class;
assert (clazz.isArray());
assert Foo.class.equals(clazz.getComponentType());
```

Asking for "the `PropertyDescriptor`" *for a class* doesn't really make sense, but perhaps you're looking for the `BeanInfo`:

```
BeanInfo infoAboutFoo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz.getComponentType());
PropertyDescriptor[] fooDescriptors = infoAboutFoo.getPropertyDescriptors();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I used a slightly modified version of the `getBeanInfo` call as follows
`BeanInfo infoAboutFoo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz.getComponentType(), Object.class);`

Answer (score 2):

You can access the component type of an array class via `Class.getComponentType()`.

Therefore to create a `BeanDescriptor` for `Foo` given `fooArray` write

```
BeanDescriptor d = new BeanDescriptor(fooArray.getClass().getComponentType());
```

The `BeanDescriptor` then allows you to retrieve the `PropertyDescriptor` for all `Foo` bean properties.